# Show recent posts in single-post page

Tags: archives, get-posts, recent-posts

I'm trying to show recent custom posts in `single-events.php` I can make it work by using `get_posts` what I don't know how to do is exclude the post that is active so if I'm on 'Event 1' just now using the code below it will show 'Event 1' in the 'Recent Events' section. How do I get around this?

```
<?php

$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'events', 
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
```

/* EDIT */

I was missing this: `'exclude' => $post->ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) accepts a parameter 'post__not_in', which allows you to specify an array of post IDs to exclude from the query. `get_posts()` is just a wrapper for `WP_Query`, so the documentation for this parameter can be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters).

When inside the loop (such as inside `single-events.php`) you can retrieve the current post's ID with `get_the_ID()` ([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)). So the following should work:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'events', 
    'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you, before you answered I used `'exclude' => $post->ID` is this effectively doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, pretty much: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.8/wp-includes/post.php#L1697

Comment: In the _Tekken_ game series that was called a _Mirror Match!_.